# Major issue resolving circular reference in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have say 3 products A,B and C. A customer can choose anyone and they have to simply type "yes".

Problem:
I wish to enter "yes" in product A, which will result in "no" for products B and C.
Similarly, if the client chooses product B , then A and C will show "no".

Kindly help me with the issue . 
Need your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume A1:A3 is product captions, B1:B3 is user selection.

Put the next code to the worksheet module:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Static busy As Boolean
Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, r0 As Range
If busy Then Exit Sub
Set r0 = Range("B1:B3") ' User selection range
busy = True
Set r = Application.Intersect(Target, r0)
If r Is Nothing Then
    busy = False
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each r1 In r
        If r1.Value = "yes" Then
            r0.Value = "no"
            r1.Value = "yes"
            Exit For
        Else
            r1.Value = "no"
        End If
    Next
    busy = False
End If
End Sub
```

Remember - when copy-pasting a range to user selection range, most upper "yes" is accepted and all another are ignored. If there is "yes" value, all another values are replaced with "no".

Maybe some errors caused wrong result in some special cases exists - debug them.

Of course, any literals can be edited or replaced with variables stored proper values.